# callback data get string instead bool aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Aiogram 2v. When i use callback data, instead bool i get string.
How can i fix this in aiogram 2? I know how to do it in aiogram 3, but it beta.

```html
callback_data = faq_callback.new(action='faqAct' ,id=int(i.get('id')),iftext=bool(hastext)))
```

But i get "True" "False". How i can get bool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you always get a value in `'True'` and `'False'` in string format you can convert them to `bool` by comparing with `'True'`:

```
callback_data = faq_callback.new(action='faqAct' ,id=int(i.get('id')),iftext=bool(hastext))) == 'True'
```

So, it will compare `faq_callback.new()` with string `'True'` ; if it is correct it will give Boolean True; if `faq_callback.new()` is `'False'` it will give Boolean False .

Both these Boolean `True/False` will be assigned to `callback_data`

Comment: please accept my answer is it was useful to you